# XMPP iOS authentication error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I have tried to authenticate on secured openfire server from iOS using XMPP, but i have received following :

```
Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=4 "No suitable authentication method found" UserInfo=0x79726370 {NSLocalizedDescription=No suitable authentication method found}
```

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved my issue by deleting `sasl.mechs` from System Properties in openfire.

For more details, you can refer my question on github at following link:

> https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/576